# How to send parameter as URL in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my javascript code:

```
onClick="buyWineNew1('+urlmerchant+','+merchantId+','+wineID+');"
```

Throws this error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>   buyWineNew1(or.org or.net,1,1)
>   -----------------^

here parameter as urlmerchant, merchantId, wineID

When clicking buyWineNew1  showing error as ->SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
     buyWineNew1(or.org or.net,1,1)

Comment: What is `or.org or.net`? Is that supposed to be a string?

Comment: What is the question? Is this really the code that you run? How does `buyWineNew1` look? Could you give a small working example?

Comment: The line you've posted (assuming it is an inline click handler) doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: is urlmerchant, merchantId, and windID JavaScript variables?  If so you don't need the single quotes at all buyWineNew1(urlmerchant, merchantId, wineID);

Comment: or.org or.net is a URL like ( http://example.com) in this html page load dynamically..

Comment: @sachin We cant (maybe can, but are not really supposed to) guess whats wrong with your code. You have to show us some of the real code so that we can actually see what is wrong. Answering this correct would currently just be a lucky hit. Show the function `buyWineNew1` and if the onClick call looks anything different in the original code, please show that too.

Answer (score 2):

This is assuming you are adding an onclick by building a string. AKA

```
var str = '<a href="" onclick="" ...
```

You are not wrapping the string with quotes.

```
onClick="buyWineNew1('+urlmerchant+','+merchantId+','+wineID+');"
```

need to be

```
onClick="buyWineNew1(\''+urlmerchant+'\','+merchantId+','+wineID+');"
                     ^^               ^^
```

Notice the `\'` where the `\` is escaping the `'` so it is not seen as closing the string. Now if any of the values contain a `"` or `'`, the code will also break.  That is why adding events inline is a bad idea and adding them unobtrusively is a better idea.

Comment: urlmerchant =http://example.com

Comment: Which is a string...

Comment: thank you sir i got answer..

Comment: Mark this as the answer, do not post what I wrote as your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addslashes(string) {
    return string.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\').
        replace(/\u0008/g, '\\b').
        replace(/\t/g, '\\t').
        replace(/\n/g, '\\n').
        replace(/\f/g, '\\f').
        replace(/\r/g, '\\r').
        replace(/'/g, '\\\'').
        replace(/"/g, '\\"');
}
```

use the above function and add slashes before passing it.